# Extending sbt-native-packager (Docker)

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I'm having a problem with sbt-native-packager's Docker module.  It uses an (overridable) bash template but this template has ${{template_declares}} that substitutes some important project information into the bash file.

My problem is I can't use bash--I'm using busybox, which uses ash.  Some of the generated stuff from sbt is incompatible with ash.  Specifically the code dropped in for ${{template_declares}} is incompatible and I need to have it generate something different.

I see there are both Windows and bash "generators" predefined.  How can I make an ash generator that modifies the bash version?

I can certainly clone the repo and make an ash generator but I'm hoping to extend rather than clone.  I've never extended a sbt plugin.  How is that done?

Comment: Hey - you asked this question quite some time ago - either accept one of the answers provided, clarify your question, or [delete it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things have changed since the OP first opened the question. There is also a `AshScriptPlugin` which is better suited to a Docker container running alpine.

```
enablePlugin(AshScriptPlugin)
```

You can find out more in the [current docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/misc_archetypes.html#ashscript-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the `bash-script` is incompatible as busy-box requires `ash` scripts.

You can simply [override the startscript](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html?highlight=bash#overriding-templates-bash-bat). Just put the content in a file under

```
src/templates/bash-template
```

and write your own start script.